# Naturality of Suspension

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a question about an argument used in the proof of a nameless lemma introduced below. Source: P. May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology"; page 98). Here the excerpt:

[image]

The author claims that it  suffice to show that $\Sigma \partial_{n-1} \circ \partial $ null homotopic by **naturality of $\Sigma$ ?**

In what way does it make sense? $\Sigma$ is suspension (functor) that maps top space $X$ to $\Sigma X := X \times S^1 /(\{*\} \times S^1 \cup X \times \{1\})$ (see page 57).

I don't see how one can give $\Sigma$ meaning as a natural transformation after passing to homology; therefore applying $H_n(-)$ to the diagram.

Comment: Suspension is the natural transformation between the functors $H_{n-1}$ and $H_n$.

Comment: @Steve D: But to claim that it suffice to show $\Sigma \partial_{n-1} \circ \partial \sim 0$ we need also that $\Sigma_*$ are isomorphisms and therefore doesn't chage to homotopy type, right?

Comment: If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map, then $\Sigma f:\Sigma X\rightarrow \Sigma Y$ is the map $\Sigma f[x,t]=[f(x),t]$, where $[x.t]\in\Sigma X\cong X\times I/\sim$. That is, suspension is a functor $\Sigma:Top\rightarrow Top$. The naturality that the author is referring to is in the sense of it being a functor.

Comment: In particular he is using that $(\Sigma \pi)\circ(\Sigma i)\simeq \Sigma(\pi\circ i)\simeq \Sigma\ast\simeq \ast$.

Answer (score 1):

May uses the same symbol $\Sigma$ to denote the suspension functor (defined for based spaces) and the map  $\Sigma : \tilde{H}'_n(X) \to \tilde{H}'_{n+1}(\Sigma X)$. For the sake of precision let us denote the latter map by $\tilde{\Sigma}$. As Steve D remarked, $\tilde{\Sigma}$ is a *natural transformation* from the functor $\tilde{H}'_n$ to the functor $\tilde{H}'_{n+1} \circ \Sigma$ which are both living on the category of based $(n−1)$-connected spaces and based continuous maps between such spaces. This was not explicitly proved by May, but is fairly easy to verify.

In fact $\tilde{\Sigma} : \tilde{H}'_{n-1}(X^{n-1}/X^{n-2}) \to \tilde{H}'_n(\Sigma(X^{n-1}/X^{n-2}))$ is an isomorphism by a previous lemma which justifies to use $\tilde{\Sigma}^{-1}$ in the definition of $d_n$.

Instead of $d_{n-1} \circ d_n = 0$ May proves the equivalent $d'_{n-1} \circ d'_n = 0$.

As Tyrone remarked, $\Sigma \pi \circ \Sigma i$ is inessential by functoriality of $\Sigma$ which implies that $\Sigma \partial_{n-1} \circ \partial_n \simeq 0$ and therefore $(\Sigma \partial_{n-1})_\ast \circ (\partial_n)_\ast = (\Sigma \partial_{n-1} \circ \partial_n)_\ast = 0$.

But now $\tilde{\Sigma} \circ (\partial_{n-1})_\ast  = (\Sigma \partial_{n-1})_\ast \circ \tilde{\Sigma}$ by naturality of $\tilde{\Sigma}$ (this is how the last sentence in your screenshot should be read). Hence

$$(\partial_{n-1})_\ast \circ \tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} =  \tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} \circ (\Sigma \partial_{n-1})_\ast$$
and
$$d'_{n-1} \circ d'_n = \tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} \circ (\partial_{n-1})_\ast \circ \tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} \circ (\partial_n)_\ast = \tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} \circ \tilde{\Sigma}^{-1} \circ (\Sigma \partial_{n-1})_\ast \circ (\partial_n)_\ast = 0 .$$

Comment: May, not Hatcher. (Otherwise, very nicely written; changing notation makes this much cleaner.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you, I shall correct this.